# Subquery returned more than 1 value.4...Different query

Tags: mysql

Hello I have this query that i am trying to execute and i keep getting this error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.", Kindly help please.

```
DECLARE @NUMCOUNT BIT

Select @NUMCOUNT = (SELECT 
CASE WHEN 


(SELECT COUNT(R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ) 

       WHERE R5REQUISLINES.RQL_STATUS IN ('A')
       ) IN 
(SELECT   COUNT(R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ)  

       WHERE R5REQUISLINES.RQL_STATUS IN ( 'A','C') ) THEN 1 else  0 END AS NUMCOUNT1
       FROM         R5REQUISLINES JOIN
                      R5REQUISITIONS ON R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ = R5REQUISITIONS.REQ_CODE

       GROUP BY R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ, R5REQUISITIONS.REQ_CODE,R5REQUISLINES.RQL_STATUS

 )

IF @NUMCOUNT = '1'

begin

UPDATE R5REQUISITIONS

SET R5REQUISITIONS.REQ_STATUS = 'CP'

end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you provide any sample data? Your query is failing because the query assigning a value to @NUMCOUNT is returning 1 value per record in the join between `R5REQUISLINES` and `R5REQUISITIONS`.

Comment: I am trying to compare records from R5REQUISLINES with status "A" and status "A, C", if the the count at the same then update the status to "CP" on another table R5REQUISITIONS. I am using the join to reference the R5REQUISITIONS ON R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ = R5REQUISITIONS.REQ_CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it sounds like what you *actually* want to do is update `R5REQUISITIONS` when there is no `RQL_STATUS = 'C'` in `R5REQUISLINES`, since you said you want to count the records where the `RQL_STATUS` is A and where it's A or C, and then do the update if the counts are the same.. You can greatly simplify this task with the following query:

```
UPDATE r5
SET r5.REQ_STATUS = 'CP'
FROM R5REQUISITIONS r5
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM R5REQUISLINES r5q WHERE r5q.RQL_REQ = r5.REQ_CODE AND r5q.RQL_STATUS = 'C')
```

Comment: I want to update R5REQUISITIONS when there is no RQL_STATUS = 'C' in R5REQUISLINES, since you said you want to count the records where the RQL_STATUS is A and where it's A and C, because there are different lines in REREQUISLINES which could be A and C and these lines can exist in one REEQUISITIONS line with status A  and then do the update if the counts are the same

Comment: I don't really understand your comment, @user3035565. It looks like most of it was just copied from my answer, but I'll try to answer the best I can.  RQL_STATUS is only a column in R5REQUISLINES, yes? So if the count where the RQL_STATUS is in ('A') is equal to the count when RQL_STATUS is in ('A','C'), then that means the count can only be the same if there is no 'C' RQL_STATUS. Using this deduction, we can simplify the task to "Update when there is no R5REQUISLINES.RQL_STATUS = 'C' for this R5REQUISITIONS.REQ_CODE"

Answer (score -1):

Your 'SELECT CASE' is returning more than 1 record, so it can't be assigned to @NUMBER.  Either fix the sub-query to only return the record your looking for or hack it to return only 1 with a 'LIMIT 1'  qualification.

I don't know what your data looks like so I can't tell you why your case subquery returns more records than you think it should.

Try running this and see what it returns, that will probably tell you wall you need to know:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN
        (SELECT COUNT(R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ)
            WHERE R5REQUISLINES.RQL_STATUS IN ('A')
        ) IN 
        (SELECT COUNT(R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ)
            WHERE R5REQUISLINES.RQL_STATUS IN ( 'A','C') 
        ) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END AS NUMCOUNT1
    FROM R5REQUISLINES JOIN
        R5REQUISITIONS ON R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ = R5REQUISITIONS.REQ_CODE
    GROUP BY R5REQUISLINES.RQL_REQ, R5REQUISITIONS.REQ_CODE,R5REQUISLINES.RQL_STATUS
```

If there is more than 1 row returned, that's where your problem is.

Comment: Yes it did return more than one row. that's because it is comparing more than one row and I need the 1 and 0 to determine which row matched and which did not

Comment: That is the cause of your issue, you can't return more than 1 row and assign it to a single variable.  You asked why you were getting that error, that's the reason.  If you need to use multiple rows, you're going to need to refactor your solution.